# Protocol delegate between view before navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue, protocols

`View1` segues to **Navigation Controller** - `View2` segues to `View3`

I am trying to create protocol delegate from View3 to View1

In View1

```
class NormalUser: UIViewController, NormalUserDelegate {

    @objc func showAddressView() {
        addressView.isHidden = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let conn = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View") as? View
        {
            conn.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

In View3

```
weak var delegate: NormalUserDelegate?

func test() {

self.delegate?.showAddressView()

}
```

**Protocol**

```
protocol NormalUserDelegate: class {
    func showAddressView()
}
```

I couldn't make it work. Any idea?

Comment: I guess it is better to use NSnotifications in this case

Comment: The reason you’re not getting answers is that your question isn’t at all clear. Don’t make us decipher your code in order to figure out what you’re trying to ask, and give us more information about how you’re failing than “I couldn’t make it work.” Also, view controllers are not views, so calling them “View1” and “View3” just makes your question harder to understand.

Comment: In your example, `conn` is out of scope after `viewDidLoad`. The `delegate` member of View3 is marked as `weak`, so the reference to it is lost when `viewDidLoad` returns. To make your code work you'd have to either make `conn` a member of the View1 class or delete the `weak` keyword on the `delegate` member of View3.

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz, Please share a demo project which reproduces the same problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, you have 2 decent options to use a delegate pattern. 1 terrible option that will work but it's hacky and lazy, and then you have the broadcast receiver pattern.

## 2 decent options

### 1 - Pass the delegate forward

```swift
class VC1: UIViewController, SomeDelegate {

    func delegateFunction() {}

    func showNextVC() {
        let next = VC2()
        next.forwardingDelegate = self
        present(next, animated: true)
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    var forwardingDelegate: SomeDelegate? = nil

    func showNextVC() {
        let next = VC3()
        next.delegate = forwardingDelegate
        present(next, animated: true)
    }
}
```

### 2 - Pass the 3rd controller to the second controller

```swift
class VC1: UIViewController, SomeDelegate {

    func delegateFunction() {}

    func showNextVC() {
        let final = VC3()
        final.delegate = self

        let next = VC2(withControllerToPresent: final)
        present(next, animated: true)
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    let controller: UIViewController

    init(withControllerToPresent controller: UIViewController) {
        self.controller = controller
        super.init(withNibName: nil, bundle: nil 
    }

    func showNextVC() {
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}

class VC3: UIViewController { 
    var delegate: SomeDelegate? = nil
}
```

## 1 Terrible Option

Use a singleton/global var.... (please dont)

## Personal Opinion

I've done both of the first two options... They work. But the broadcast receiver pattern is probably better because it would be cleaner. VC2 shouldn't need to forward anything to 3. Just make sure to namespace your notification specific enough to not catch it by anything else later.

Comment: Note, this does not use a storyboard.

Comment: Although I think you can still do this, just make properties in your files as IBoutlet and connect them in the story board

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you need two delegates, each one passing data back to the previous UIViewController. You cannot bypass the secondary UIViewController as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is a router class, this is a simple example of how I would implement it.

```
protocol RoutingView1{
func openView2()
}

protocol RoutingView2{
func openView3()
}

protocol RoutingView3{
func foo()
}

class View1{

func foo(){
//this will get called when View3 calls its RootingView3.foo()
}
}

class Router: RoutingView1, RoutingView2{

var rootView: View1

func start() -> UIViewController{
view.routingDelegate = self
rootView = view1
}

func openView2(){
let vc = View2()
vc.routingDelegate = self
rootView.push()
}

func openView3(){
let vc = View3()
vc.routingDelegate = self
rootView.push()
}

func foo(){
rootView.foo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Unwind Segues

If you're using interface builder it may be easiest/cleanest to use unwind segues.

1. Create an interface builder action in VC1:

   ```swift
   class VC1: UIViewController {

       @IBAction func backToVC1(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
           self.showAddress()
       }

       func showAddress() {
           addressView.isHidden = false
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your storyboard for VC3 control-click on the view controller icon, drag the mouse over the exit icon and release. Click to select the unwind segue you created in VC1.

   [image]
3. Once you create the segue select it in the document outline.

   [image]
4. And name it in the attributes inspector.

   [image]
5. Finally, call the segue in your VC3 code.

   ```swift
   class VC3: UIViewController {

       func test() {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToVC1", sender: self)
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `SwiftEventBus` for this situation. [Link](https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus)

**Example:**

```
@IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
     count++
     SwiftEventBus.post("doStuffOnBackground")
 }

 @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

 var count = 0

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     SwiftEventBus.onBackgroundThread(self, name: "doStuffOnBackground") { notification in
         println("doing stuff in background thread")
         SwiftEventBus.postToMainThread("updateText")
     }

     SwiftEventBus.onMainThread(self, name: "updateText") { notification in
         self.textField.text = "\(self.count)"
     }
}

//Perhaps on viewDidDisappear depending on your needs
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    SwiftEventBus.unregister(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Just set delegate of view 2 as a delegate of view 3 as below:**

 class View1: UIViewController, NormalUserDelegate {

       @objc func showAddressView() {

            addressView.isHidden = false
        }
    // Going to view 2 by any means i.e segue , navigation set  
       func goToView2Controller(){
         if let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View2") as? View2
            {
              view2.delegate = self
            }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

       }
    }

    class View2: UIViewController {
     weak var delegate: NormalUserDelegate?

    // Going to view 3 by any means i.e segue or other means  
       func goToView3Controller(){
         if let view3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View3") as? View3
            {
              view3.delegate = self.delegate
            }
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view3, animated: true)
       }

    }

    class View3: UIViewController {
     weak var delegate: NormalUserDelegate?


    func test() {

      self.delegate?.showAddressView()

    }

    }
```